# Writing equation with explaining instruction shown as in example image

Tags: equations

I need to write equation with explaining instruction as shown in attached image in latex,[image]

Can anyone help me.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30090/263192 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522517/263192 might help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,it answer the question.